# If $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in an (Archimedean) ordered field K, is K a complete ordered field?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

Let K be an ordered field. Then K contains the smallest ordered filed $\mathbb{Q}$.

1. If $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense and proper in K, is K a complete ordered field?
2. If $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense and proper in K, and K has the Archimedean property, is K a complete ordered field?

(i.e. satisfying any one of the equivalent definitions of a complete ordered field.) (If you know the answer you may give hints first.)

Comment: Have you thought about the case $K=\Bbb Q$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: You are right. I have to edit or delete this post...

Comment: There are many such ordered fields, such as the reals of the form $a+b\sqrt{3}$, where $a$ and $b$ are rational, or the real algebraics.

Comment: You really might have given the matter a little thought before "fixing" the question by just adding the word "proper"...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I apologize for such possibly low quality question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  For example, consider the smallest field that includes every rational number and also $\sqrt 2$.  That is an ordered field that is not *complete*.  You can show it is not complete by using the fact that it is countable, as in [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_first_uncountability_proof).

Comment: Thank you! :) So if an ordered filed is complete then it contains a dense sub ordered filed. But the converse is not true.

Comment: Correct. ${}\qquad{}$